# PDO insert with $_POST?

Tags: php, post, pdo, insert

I am trying to insert data from a simple html form with $_POST into the database with PHP and PDO. I am not getting any errors, there is just nothing going into the database. If I type the values manually in the code it works but nothing happens when typing into the html form. At some point I had "Array" typed out.

**UPDATE:** 
The error I am getting is:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null' in ...

Why is Column title null?

**The database is just a table with 4 fields (id, title, message and time/timestamp field.**
The id field is primary AI and the timestamp field is picking up the time automatically.

Here is the connect.inc.php file:

```
<?php
class DB extends PDO
{
    public function __construct($dbname = "blogdata")
    {
        try {
            parent::__construct("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8",
                                "root", "");
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

And here is the post.php file:

```
<?php 

require 'connect.inc.php';

$db = new DB('blogdata');

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blogposts (title, message, time) VALUES (:title, :message, :time)");

$stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
$stmt->bindParam(':message', $_POST['message']);
$stmt->bindParam(':time', $time);

$title = $_POST['title'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$stmt->execute();

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Create blog post</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />

</head>

<body>

<!--- Add blog post ---> 

<div class="add_form">
    <form id="add_post" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="text/plain">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create post</legend>
            <label for="post_title">Title:
                <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="<?php if (isset($title)) { echo htmlentities ($title); } ?>" >
            </label>
            <label for="message">Message:
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="20" cols="30" maxlength="50" value="<?php if (isset($message)) { echo htmlentities ($message); } ?>" ></textarea>
            </label>                                        
        </fieldset>
        <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

**ANSWER**

You need to wrap everything up and check if $_POST is not empty. Also the problem was action="index.php" in the form. It needed to be set to post.php.

Here is the correct code in post.php:

```
<?php 

if (!empty($_POST)) {

  require 'connect.inc.php';

  $db = new DB('blogdata');

  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blogposts (title, message) VALUES (:title, :message)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':message', $_POST['message']);

  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $stmt->execute();

  header ('Location: index.php');
  exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Create blog post</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

<!--- Add blog post ---> 

<div class="add_form">
    <form id="add_post" method="post" action="post.php">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create post</legend>
            <label for="post_title">Title:
                <input id="title" type="text" name="title" value="<?php if (isset($title)) { echo htmlentities ($title); } ?>" >
            </label>
            <label for="message">Message:
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="20" cols="30" maxlength="50" value="<?php if (isset($message)) { echo htmlentities ($message); } ?>" ></textarea>
            </label>                                        
        </fieldset>
        <input id="send" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Put everything in a try/catch block and see if you catch any errors.

Comment: @aynber to let you know, exceptions perfectly visible WITHOUT any catch blocks

Comment: Mostly, if you know where to look :-) The catch blocks let you output it where you want if there are errors.

Comment: Where is `$time` coming from? It doesn't look as though it's defined. Also, try this in your constructor for the DB `$this->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. That may give you an error message that you're not seeing now. PDO exception output is separate from regular PHP error reporting, so even if your PHP error reporting settings are appropriate, you may not be seeing PDO exceptions.

Comment: What do you obtain if you add : `var_dump($_POST['title']); var_dump($_POST['message']); exit;` to your code ?

Comment: @aynber I know that regular PHP user have no idea of PHP errors and where to look for them, yet, they **have** to be aware of them and learn places where to look. ALL errors, not a limited subset you are talking about

Comment: @Corum Hi, Thank you for your reply! I´m getting NULL NULL when trying this out!

Comment: @YourCommonSense Point taken.

Comment: @GeekGirl : There is something strange : why do you call `index.php` in your form action while your code to process form is in `post.php` ?

Comment: @Corum Hi, I´m calling index.php in the form because index.php are displaying all the posts and after sending the form the user should be directed to index.php and be able to see the results... I really can´t seem to solve this:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awser for your last comment :

> @Corum Hi, I´m calling index.php in the form because index.php are
>   displaying all the posts and after sending the form the user should be
>   directed to index.php and be able to see the results... I really can´t
>   seem to solve this:(

If you call index.php with `<form action="index.php">` your form data will never be processed.

You have to call `post.php` instead and after redirect to index.php.

Corrected code (replace top PHP block in your file `post.php`) :

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST) {
  // Only process if form is submitted (when page is launched, it use GET method)
  require 'connect.inc.php';

  $db = new DB('blogdata');

  $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO blogposts (title, message, time) VALUES (:title, :message, :time)");

  $stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':message', $_POST['message']);
  $stmt->bindParam(':time', $time);

  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  $stmt->execute();

  // Redirect to index.php
  header('Location : index.php');
  exit;
}
?>
```

And change your html form for : `<form action="post.php" ...>`

Comment: Ok this took away the current error but the problem is still the same, data will not enter the database and after sending the form it just shows post.php no error no nothing...

Comment: Remove `enctype="text/plain"`, add `var_dump($_POST); die();` just after `if (!empty($_POST) {` and tell us what you obtain.

Comment: I obtain this: array(2) { ["title"]=> string(5) "super" ["message"]=> string(11) "bhbhbgkbgkj" }

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the "id" column and "timestamp" column. Maybe the database is not picking up a new id? This array is only showing title and message fields...

Comment: I´ve tried this before but not sure exactly what value to give since it´s the current time. $title = $_POST['title']; $message = $_POST['message']; But $time = what? It can´t be $_POST since it´s not in the form. What value should I give?

Comment: I can't write all code for you : you have to try yourself too. Add a field to your form to populate time or set a default value.

Comment: I know but believe me I´m trying, I´ve been trying all day:/ I don´t want a time field in the form, it shouldn´t have to be a time field since it should be able to register current time automatically. It´s not problem when I write the title and message values in the code but as soon as I´m typing something in the form it does not work...:( Thank´s anyway for the help! I really  appreciate you trying!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38903/discussion-between-corum-and-geekgirl)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **proper** connect.inc.php file:

```
<?php
class DB extends PDO
{
    public function __construct($dbname = "blogdata")
    {
        $opt = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8";
        parent::__construct($dsn, "root", "", $opt);
    }
}
```

Dunno if it caused error but

> And here is the **post.php** file:
>   `<form` id="add_post" method="post" action="**index.php**"

Anyway, the real cause of the problem is similar to that. Some silly typo somewhere

Comment: Hi! I just change to this and received this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'title' cannot be null' in

Comment: It seems that the values are zero in all the fields... I thought it had something do to with the ID field and AI so I have tried adding this: $newId = $db->lastInsertId();

Comment: That's exactly what you were looking for. Now you can either read and comprehend this error yourself, or google for that (nota thet meaningful part starts from " Integrity")

Comment: I just can´t see what the problem is... The <form id="add_post" method="post" action="index.php" is posting to index.php because on index.php is where the posts are displaying and after sending the form you are directed to index.php... Does not anyone know why it is not working?